# Get total from multiple class onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goodday, i'm trying to get total and grandtotal from textinput . First please check my script

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

 <tr>
  <td>No</td>
  <td>Item</td>
  <td>Qty</td>
  <td>est</td>
  <td>tax</td>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td>GrandTotal</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>No</td>
  <td>ITEM 1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="est"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="tax"></td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly class="total"></td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly class="grandtotal"></td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>No</td>
 <td>ITEM 1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="est"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="tax"></td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly class="total"></td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly class="grandtotal"></td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

As you can i see, there is `.total` and `.grandtotal`. I want to get it with this

```
total = .est * .qty
grandtotal = .total * .tax
```

So, i want to onchange in two fields `.est` & `.tax` .

Maybe i can do this

```
$(document).on("change",".tax",function(){
           //Code
        });
```

and

```
 $(document).on("change",".tax",function(){
           //Code
        });
```

But it will take time, so i'm trying to approach this way

```
   $(document).on("change",".tax, .est",function(){
       //I don't know to get value of .tax or .est only
    });
```

How can i get the total and grandtotal ?

Comment: you set the value of the input using `.val()` like `$('.total').val(total)`

Comment: You have no element with `.persen`.

Comment: @Mamun oops, my bad. i'll update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run and see result

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var qty = $($(this).children()[2]).text(),
    $tax = $(this).find(".tax"),
    $est = $(this).find(".est"),
    $total = $(this).find(".total"),
    $grandtotal = $(this).find(".grandtotal")

  function onChange() {
    var t = $est.val() * qty
    var gt = $tax.val() * t
    $total.val(t)
    $grandtotal.val(gt)
  }

  $tax.change(onChange)
  $est.change(onChange)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>est</td>
    <td>tax</td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>GrandTotal</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>ITEM 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="est"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="tax"></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly class="total"></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly class="grandtotal"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>ITEM 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="est"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="tax"></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly class="total"></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly class="grandtotal"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: how can i handle `1,000` in `.est` ?

Comment: ah nevermind, i use this `.replace(/,/g, '').trim();`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help

```js
$(function() {
  var resultTax = 0, resultEst = 0, total = 0;
  
  $(".tax").change( function() {
      $(".tax").each(function() { 
         resultTax += parseFloat($(this).val())
      });
      
      $('.resultTax').text(resultTax);
      $('.total').text($('.resultEst').text() + $('.resultTax').text());
  });
  
  $(".est").change( function() {
      $(".est").each(function() { 
         resultEst += parseFloat($(this).val())
      });
      
      $('.resultEst').text(resultEst);
      $('.total').text(parseFloat($('.resultEst').text()) + parseFloat($('.resultTax').text()));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Tax <input type="text" class="tax" value="1"> 
Tax <input type="text" class="tax" value="2"><br>
Est <input type="text" class="est" value="3">
Est <input type="text" class="est" value="4"><br><br>
resultTax : <span class="resultTax"></span><br>
resultEst : <span class="resultEst"></span><br>
Total Tax + Est : <span class="total"></span>
```